# How to prevent LaTeX from repositioning a "longtblr"?

Tags: tables, positioning, longtable, tabularray, longtblr

I have 4 tables in a row. Two of them are `longtblr` (i.e. the first and the last tables), and two are `table` (i.e. the second and the third tables). The last table, i.e. `longtblr` gets repositioned by Latex in an unexpected position.

How to prevent LaTeX from repositioning a `longtblr`?

For example, I would like to use the `H` placement option (e.g. `\begin{longtblr}[H]`) to make sure that my long table doesn't get repositioned.

Comment: I don't understand your question: the `longtblr` environment is NOT floating.

Comment: It is what I also thought, but once I add a 5th ```longtblr``` to my document, Latex places it in an unexpected position (i.e. between other tables, in another page)... However, if I wrap my long table with ```table```, i.e.  as ```\begin{table}[ht] \begin{longtblr}[theme = ...,```, it goes to the right position (as expected), but then, my long table remains within one page, and it does not continue in the following pages... Any idea about this behaviour and how to avoid it?

Comment: do not put a longtable or a longtblr in a table environment!! the only purpose of `table` is to allow it to move and it also prevents page breaking which is the point of using `longtblr`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was just a try :-) I will not wrap ```longtblr``` with ```table```

Answer (score -1):

Altough I do not know if it is robust, and if it is going to work also after further modifications to my tables, I found a possible workaround for my case, where I have two `longtblr` (i.e. the first and the last tables) and two `table` (i.e. the second and the third tables):

```
% first
\begin{longtblr}[theme =  
       ...
\end{longtblr}


% second
\begin{table}[H]
       ...
\end{table}


% third
\begin{table}[H]
       ...
\end{table}

\pagebreak


% fourth
\begin{longtblr}[theme = 
       ...
\end{longtblr}
```

Basically, I played a bit with the positioning option of the two `table` (and at the end I used `H`), and I added a `\pagebreak` just before the last `longtblr`.

Comment: Instead of using some `table` with `[H]` specifier, use `longtblr` for all your tables...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did it and it works, if you want to put it as an answer, I will accept it :-) And I will delete my workaround since it gots a "-1"